# App submission with database

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sqlite

How to submit an application to the app store with my database (.sqlite) included within the application? Being only need to copy to the directory and use the database.

I tried normal submission with the database (.sqlite) within the application but was rejected by the item 2:23 from [App Store Review GuideLines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of rejection is:

```
2.23
Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected
```

Please DO NOT copy the file to Documents folder. Document is intended for user generated files (users can see these files in itunes). You can copy the file to a subfolder of Library folder and add [addSkipBackupAttribute](https://gist.github.com/tibr/1999985) to the subfolder to prevent the file from being backed up to iCloud.

Add the line code to not back up to iCloud:

```
[URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
```

And copied the database to directory `Library/Caches`

Answer (score 2):

If your app uses a local sqlite database just make sure that database is included in your bundle (just like image files). You then access it via the bundle (again, similar to image files). Where is your database located currently?

Edit: The other answer provides more info - I was looking at the wrong submission guideline.

Comment: Hi kmcgrady, currently is included in your bundle (just like image files) and copied to directory app Documents on device and accessed from this directory.

Comment: Then that's all you needed. Just build and submit your app. Your rejection reason is normally the one given for a crash/bug. You should ask for specific guidance from the reviewer in the resolution centre.

Comment: Ok, I will review the project and build and apply again. Thank you